# Getting RSA key size from modulus string in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rsa, public-key-encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

In C# we have a way to figure out RSA key size from modulus string like shown below,

Is there a similar way to get key size in JavaScript or typescript?

```
var bytesModulus = Convert.FromBase64String(modulusString);

using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
 var rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

 rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
 rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);

 return rsa.KeySize;
}
```

Comment: Did you see [this library](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key is following the rules of making the modulus be between `2^(8n - 1)` and `(2^(8n) - 1)` you only need to know the byte length for the modulus (then multiply by 8).

After removing any white space the answer would be:

- Hexadecimal: the string `length * 4` (length / 2 is bytes, * 8 to get bits)
- Base64: `((length + 3) / 4) * 24` — or if you are only getting the =-padded version: `length * 6` (length / 4 * 3 bytes, * 8 for bits, reduces to * 3 * 2 when the input is known to be a multiple of 4)
- Decimal string: harder. Without a bignum library you can only bound it: it’s greater than `length * 3.3`, and less than `length * 6.7` (or 3 and 7, if you prefer).
- Other: Figure out the length in bytes, multiply by 8.